# query list of users after specified id in sqlalchemy.Table

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Letss say that we have 10000 users on this data table.

```
users = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column("id", sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("email", sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("registration_date", sqlalchemy.String),
)
```

If the table is **ordered by registration_date** and I have a user id, how can I query the next 2 users after that id.

e.g if this is the db table and I have the user id 1703, I want to get the next two users in the list.

```
3872    | aada.laine@example.com    | 2019-09-22T17:34:31.260Z
1703    |thn.rdyy@example.com       | 2019-09-21T02:28:58.914Z
6657    |olivia.hansen@example.com  | 2019-09-20T18:52:43.073Z
6689    |siiri.suomi@example.com    | 2019-09-20T00:16:39.334Z
```

I tried something like

```
query = users.select().where(users.c.id == 1703).limit(2)
```

but I get only the specified user as response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.registration_date > (SELECT registration_date FROM users WHERE id = 2)
ORDER BY users.registration_date
LIMIT 2
```

In SQLAlchemy, you can do that using a subquery

```py
registration_date_min = select([users.c.registration_date])\
  .where(users.c.id == 2)\
  .as_scalar()
users.select()\
  .where(users.c.registration_date > registration_date_min)\
  .order_by(users.c.registration_date)\
  .limit(2)
```

If you want strict ordering (for example when two people have the exact same registration date), then I'd order by `registration_date, id`, and use

```sql
WHERE users.registration_date > (SELECT registration_date FROM users WHERE id = 2)
   OR (users.registration_date = (SELECT registration_date FROM users WHERE id = 2)
       AND users.id > 2)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, had to make some minor fine tuning tho. 

Thank you very much!